# How to avoid Save Prompt During SendCommand on activex autocad api

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, autocad, autocad-plugin

I am trying to convert .dwg format to png/bmp.

when I use Plot in AutoCAD for converting dwg to png .

```
plot_command = "-PLOT yes base1\r\nPublishToWeb PNG.pc3\rSun Hi-Res (1600.00 x 1280.00 Pixels)\rP\rN\rE\rF\rC\rY\r.\rY\rN\rN\rN\r\n& 'D:/autocad_test/see.png'& \r\n"
doc.SendCommand(plot_command)
```

during this command Save prompt is coming. I need to override this and also save the file using this single command[image: saveprompt]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

```
doc.SendCommand("_.filedia\n0\n_.-plot\n_Y\n\nPublishToWeb PNG.pc3\nSun Hi-Res (1600.00 x 1280.00 Pixels)\n_P\n_N\n_E\n_F\n_C\n_Y\n.\n_Y\n_N\n_N\n_N\nD:/autocad_test/see.png\n_N\n_Y\n_.filedia\n1\n")
```

Note that this assumes that the file does not already exist (otherwise there would be an additional prompt to consider - you may therefore wish to incorporate additional code to account for this scenario.

Comment: Still, I am getting the same prompt